# How to pass sql parameter in DAX query in SSIS

Tags: variables, ssis, parameter-passing, ssas, dax

Does anyone know how to pass a parameter to DAX query in SSIS?

I know that when using OLEDB Source in SSIS we can use "?" to pass a parameter to the query. To further clarify, the query should look like this 'select region from table where region = ?';

Similarly, how to pass a parameter to a DAX Query within SSIS? I have tried with "@" but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the answer at last.

I captured the output of SQL query in a variable using "single Result Set" in Execute SQL task.For example var1 = "tableA"
Then I created another variable for example -DAX_Var which holds the dax query in the form of expression like this "Evaluate Summarize" + @user::var1
Bring a DFT, bring an OLE DB source. Use SQL command from variable and instead of pointing table, I point the variable name. Ie DAX_Var
In this way, I was able to connect my SQL variable and bring it inside the DAX query.

It worked Flawlessly